# "Setting" class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

i was reading a tutorial for windows phone 7  using C# and sliverlight and i found this line

```
public static class Settings
{
    public static readonly Setting<bool> IsRightHanded = 
        new Setting<bool>("IsRightHanded", true);

     public static readonly Setting<double> Threshold =
        new Setting<double>("Threshold", 1.5);
}
```

i can't find the `Setting` Class in `C#`  i wanted to know if it's under a special namespace or need an additional reference to add

Comment: Could you share a link to the example / tutorial?

Comment: unfortunately it's from a book but i can share the whole class i'll edit the comment

Comment: It's probably a custom class.

Comment: As far as I know it is not a standard type of Silverlight. 

The tutorial should give you some sort of hint...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the `Setting<T>` class that I use.  It supports change notification via `INotifyPropertyChanged` which is useful for binding (in WPF/SL/etc).  It also maintains a copy of the default value so that it may be reset if required.

As a general rule, `T` should be immutable.

```
public class Setting<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event Action<T> Changed;

    private readonly T _defaultValue;
    private T _value;

    public Setting(T defaultValue)
    {
        _defaultValue = defaultValue;
        _value = defaultValue;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(_value, value))
                return;
            _value = value;
            var evt = Changed;
            if (evt != null)
                evt(value);
            var evt2 = PropertyChanged;
            if (evt2 != null)
                evt2(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
        }
    }

    public void ResetToDefault()
    {
        Value = _defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If it is a custom class, and not described in the tutorial you got this from, can you not reimplement it? It looks to me like the class would have a signature something like this:

```
public class Setting<T> 
{
    public Setting<T>(string name, T value)
    { 
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    } 

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, there could be more to it than that. What properties are being accessed / bound to on this class in the tutorial?

Comment: it might not be the Setting class meant in the tutorial but yeah this should work properly .. thank you

Comment: A wild guess says the class also had a *behind-the-scenes* IsolatedStorage implementation/handler.

Comment: very wise. @Hady, if you google "Setting class missing <bookname>" do you get any answers? If they have made a mistake in their book it may be on the web, or in their erata at the publishers website.

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson "public string Value { get; set; }" value should be of type T.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using "101 Windows Phone 7 Apps" book, *Setting class* is implemented and explained in Chapter 20.

Comment: That's exactly the book I'm going through