# Windows Phone 7.1 missing setting class

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I'm remembering .NET by practicing WP7.
In the book in several example there is such a line

```
Setting<Color> savedColor = new Setting<Color>(“SavedColor”, Colors.White);
```

This is equivallent to NSUserDefaults in iOS I guess, but they say I'm missing a reference to a namespace to use this Setting collection, What's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725735/setting-class-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 has no Setting generic.

The WP7 equivelent of NSUserDefaults is [IsolatedStorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) which is in the `System.IO.IsolatedStorage` namespace.

MSDN Page for [IsolatedStorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks, but I found the duplicate question and they say it's explained in a later chapter